# Need help writing a test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I'm fairly new at writing classes but I'm getting better.

Below is my Class

```
public without sharing class OpportunityClass {

private ENUM OPERATION {ISINSERT, ISUPDATE, ISDELETE}  
private ENUM SEQUENCE {ISBEFORE, ISAFTER}

public OpportunityClass () {}

public void BeforeInsert (Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapNew, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapOld) {
    ShowParentDistributorNamefromDistributor(oppsMapNew, oppsMapOld, OPERATION.ISINSERT, SEQUENCE.ISBEFORE);
}

public void BeforeUpdate (Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapNew, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapOld) {
    ShowParentDistributorNamefromDistributor(oppsMapNew, oppsMapOld, OPERATION.ISUPDATE, SEQUENCE.ISBEFORE);                
}

private void ShowParentDistributorNamefromDistributor (Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapNew, Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapOld, OPERATION op, SEQUENCE seq) {
    try {

        List<Opportunity> filteredOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

        //Filter Opportunities. Make sure there's a Distributor and it          
        for(Opportunity o : oppsMapNew.values()) {

            if( (op == OPERATION.ISUPDATE && oppsMapOld.get(o.Id).Distributor__c != o.Distributor__c ) || (op == OPERATION.ISINSERT  && o.Distributor__c != null)) {
                filteredOpps.add(o);
            }
        }

        //Were there any opps that the disty changed
        if(filteredOpps.size() > 0) {
            //Use Auto5K
            Map<String, String> distributorToParentDistributorsMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Map<String, RecordType> automationRecordTypes = Utilities.getRecordTypesMap('Automation__c', true);
            List<Automation__c> distributorToParentDistributorsList = [SELECT Id, Key__c, Value__c FROM Automation__c WHERE RecordTypeId = :automationRecordTypes.get('Distributor_to_Parent_Distributor').Id];

            for(Automation__c automation : distributorToParentDistributorsList) {
                distributorToParentDistributorsMap.put(automation.Key__c, automation.Value__c);    
            }

            for(Opportunity filteredOpp : filteredOpps) {
                if(filteredOpp.Distributor__c == null) {
                    filteredOpp.ParentDistributor__c = null;
                }
                else {
                    if(distributorToParentDistributorsMap.get(filteredOpp.Distributor__c) == null) {
                        filteredOpp.ParentDistributor__c = filteredOpp.Distributor__c; 
                    }
                    else {
                        filteredOpp.ParentDistributor__c = distributorToParentDistributorsMap.get(filteredOpp.Distributor__c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //might be a good utilites in the future
    catch(Exception e) {
        Apex_Exception__c error = new Apex_Exception__c(
            Name = 'Apex Exception - ' + System.now(),
            Trigger__c ='OpportunityClass:ShowParentDistributorNamefromDistributor',
            Error_Message__c = e.getMessage() + ':' + e.getStackTraceString(),
            Exception_Type__c = e.getTypeName()
        );
        insert error;
    }
}
}
```

I created the test class below but not sure how the "BeforeUpdate" method was called even though it's not in my test class, can anybody tell me why?

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityClassTEST {
    static testMethod void createInstanceOfClass(){
        OpportunityClass opp = new OpportunityClass();
        System.Assert(opp!=null, 'Should have created instance of class');
    }

    static testMethod void createOppWithDistributor(){
        OpportunityClass opp = new OpportunityClass();

        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapOld = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMapNew = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        Opportunity newOpp = TestUtilities.getOpp('testopp1', 'open', system.today(), 'USA - DISTRIBUTOR', 'evaltest1', false);

        String PARENT_DISTRIBUTOR = 'USA'; 
        String DISTRIBUTOR = 'USA - DISTRIBUTOR';

        Map<String, RecordType> automationRecordTypes = Utilities.getRecordTypesMap('Automation__c', true);

        SetupAutomation(DISTRIBUTOR, PARENT_DISTRIBUTOR);

        oppsMapNew.put(newOpp.Id, newOpp);

        Test.startTest();
        opp.BeforeInsert(oppsMapNew, oppsMapOld);
        Test.stopTest();        

        //now get the Opportunity and verify the Parent Distributor is correct
        //newOpp = [SELECT Id, Parent_Distributor__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :newOpp.Id];
        //System.Assert(newOpp.Parent_Distributor__c == 'USA');
    }

    private static void SetupAutomation(String PARENT_DISTRIBUTOR, String DISTRIBUTOR) {
        Map<String, RecordType> automationRecordTypes = Utilities.getRecordTypesMap('Automation__c', true);
        Automation__c automation = TestUtilities.getAutomation(PARENT_DISTRIBUTOR, DISTRIBUTOR, automationRecordTypes.get('Distributor_to_Parent_Distributor').Id, true);
        System.Assert(automation.Id!=null, 'Should have inserted automation record');
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I created the test class below but not sure how the "BeforeUpdate" method was called even though it's not in my test class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a Before update trigger on Opportunity that is calling `OpportunityClass.BeforeUpdate()` and passing it the trigger context properties.

Have a look for it at: *your name* > App Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Triggers

[image: Opportunity Before Update Trigger]

There is more general information on Triggers in the [documentation](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_define_trigger.htm).

Comment: @FridayLandon, Great. Glad to help. If the answer is correct you can mark it as such using a green tick next to the voting buttons. You may want to do this for any previous questions you have asked that have been answered successfully.